# How to check whether running on Lion or Snow Leopard

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, osx-lion

In my Cocoa application I would like to let the user take the app full screen on Lion. To do this I would like to add the following:

```
if (check for lion or above) {
    [mywindow setCollectionBehavior:NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary];
}
```

I am adding this conditionally for Lion because 
NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary is only available from 10.7. What is the best way towards the check for lion or above?

Comment: Normally you should check for feature availability instead of OS version, but I'm not sure how to test for a constant's availability.

Comment: With my app, I just selected ***Full Screen: Primary*** in interface builder. It works in Lion, and doesn't show up in Snow Leopard.

Comment: @spudwaffle This will produce warning "Full Screen Behavior on Mac OS X prior to 10.7" if deployment target is < 10.7

Comment: You can ignore that warning. It's just telling you that it won't work below Lion. If you want to be safe, though, I recommend @Macmade's answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should read documentation about the `Gestalt` function.

```
SInt32 MacVersion;

if( Gestalt( gestaltSystemVersion, &MacVersion ) == noErr )
{
    if( MacVersion == 0x1050 ) /* Mac OS X 10.5.0 */
    {}
    else
    {}
}
```

Or you can use the SysCTL API

Comment: Definitely split the `Gestalt()` call into three calls for major, minor, and bugfix versions!

Comment: No, don't use Gestalt. Use respondsToSelector: to determine if NSWindowCollectionBehaviorFullScreenPrimary is available on the target class. Not only is this better than using a deprecated API, it's also future-proof. You're using Cocoa now. Don't go back to the bad old days of checking the OS version number.